# Thread not waking up when it should

Tags: java, multithreading

The apply ketchup thread doesn't wake up and I don't know why!

I'm learning about Java thread interaction.

I did use the notifyAll() method, but the "applyKetchup" thread couldn't wake up on time！

The thread should have enough time to wake up,it's unbelievable.

The expected result is

```
makeBread！applyKetchup！makeBread！applyKetchup！makeBread！applyKetchup！makeBread！applyKetchup！makeBread！applyKetchup！
```

The actual result is

```
makeBread！applyKetchup！makeBread！makeBread！makeBread！makeBread！applyKetchup！applyKetchup！applyKetchup！applyKetchup！
```

this is my code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProduceHamburgers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HamburgerFactory hamburgerFactory = new HamburgerFactory();
        hamburgerFactory.delivery(5);
    }
}

class HamburgerFactory {

    private ArrayList<Hamburger> hamburgers = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Hamburger> breads = new ArrayList<>();

    public void delivery(int amount) {
        for (int index = 0; index < amount; index++) {
            new Thread(() -> applyKetchup(), "applyKetchup-" + index).start();
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < amount; index++) {
            new Thread(() -> makeBread(), "makeBread-" + index).start();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void applyKetchup() {
        while (breads.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Hamburger current = breads.get(0);
        breads.remove(current);
        current.hadKetchup = true;
        System.out.print("applyKetchup！");
        hamburgers.add(current);
    }

    private synchronized void makeBread() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        breads.add(new Hamburger());
        System.out.print("makeBread！");
        this.notifyAll();
    }

}

class Hamburger {
    public boolean hadKetchup = false;
}
```

thanks in advance！

Comment: I guess they prefer mayo at their hamburger. Jokes aside, your title is weird (too context-based), it should be something like "thread not waking up when expected" or w/e.

Comment: Please excuse my poor English.you are right.Jokes aside,Why is that？@Ssr1369

Comment: Because your title should summarize what's your problem about, and "ketchup" is not a concept programmers are familiar with related to programming. Threads is. Don't worry I proposed an edit that should make that better, and your question is fine. :)

Comment: This is classical producer consumer case. I think makeBread should wait on `!breads.isEmpty()`. just like applyKetchup is waiting on breads.empty() and add notify in applyKetchup().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProduceHamburgers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HamburgerFactory hamburgerFactory = new HamburgerFactory();
        hamburgerFactory.delivery(5);
    }
}

class HamburgerFactory {

    private ArrayList<Hamburger> hamburgers = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Hamburger> breads = new ArrayList<>();

    public void delivery(int amount) {
        for (int index = 0; index < amount; index++) {
            new Thread(() -> applyKetchup(), "applyKetchup-" + index).start();
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < amount; index++) {
            new Thread(() -> makeBread(), "makeBread-" + index).start();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void applyKetchup() {
        while (breads.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Hamburger current = breads.get(0);
        breads.remove(current);
        current.hadKetchup = true;
        System.out.print("applyKetchup！");
        hamburgers.add(current);
        this.notifyAll();
    }

    private synchronized void makeBread() {
         while (!breads.isEmpty()) {
             try {
                 this.wait();
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
        breads.add(new Hamburger());
        System.out.print("makeBread！");
        this.notifyAll();
    }

}

class Hamburger {
    public boolean hadKetchup = false;
}
```

O/P
makeBread！applyKetchup！makeBread！applyKetchup！makeBread！applyKetchup！makeBread！applyKetchup！makeBread！applyKetchup！

Comment: @ialam  thank you very much.but my question is why didn't it wake up correctly in the previous code? There's plenty of time to wake up.:)

Comment: Due to sleep the lock was acquired on the the HamburgerFactory object by makeBread thread. so the applyKetchup thread couldn't enter the critical section of applyKetchup. Since the applyKetchup thread was in wait state and it all depends on thread scheduler now to schedule the run of ketchup thread. On the other hand makeBread thread was just in sleep state and can directly go to run state. Till the thread scheduler have scheduled the applyKetchup thread, makeBread thread have executed several time at an interval of 100ms. So your output is like that. Hope this make it clear for you.

Comment: You can find lots of online resource on **sleep vs wait** which will make your idea more clearer on this.